# Owl Carousel scrolling with inertia

Tags: horizontal-scrolling, owl-carousel, smooth-scrolling, owl-carousel-2

I am using Owl Carousel on a mobile website.

When the user scrolls horizontally and then stops, the content stops moving immediately (or very shortly after the stop).

Is it possible to add some inertia?

I tried different options exposed in the docs, such as `smartSpeed`, `fluidSpeed`...

Comment: Do you mean like an infinite scrolling and you stop by a still press or only a more smooth transition between one item to another? Like this one: https://flickity.metafizzy.co/options.html#freescroll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking at an Infinite loop in which also you can stop in the "center" of an Item and with a smooth scrolling inertia I think that's not possible.

It's a long time issue/request that up to this answer is not still possible:

- https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/2219
- https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/1808
- https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/1859

You can look at different scrolling plugin like that [flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co).

This has a free smooth scrolling with this [option](https://flickity.metafizzy.co/options.html#freescroll).